# How to access Salesforce managed site pages without writing the namespace prefix?

Tags: salesforce, package, visualforce

We're working on a Salesforce managed package that contains visualforce pages that are to be published on a Salesforce site.

When testing, we can access those pages at `http://example.force.com/pagename`

But when installing the managed package on a testing org, we can only access those pages is prepending the package namespace, `http://example.force.com/namespace__pagename`

How can I make the pages accessible at `/pagename` even when accessing from a managed package instalation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL rewriter might possibly work but I'm pretty sure you'll find no way around this — the point of the namespaces is to prevent naming conflicts between packages, being able to remove it from the page URL would mean there's nothing to stop your package from conflicting with other packages or custom VF pages in the orgs the package is installed on.

Comment: I ended up implementing an URL rewriter. Customers will be able to use it directly, or implement their own to avoid conflicts. Instructions will be given with the package explaining the situation. Thanks!